# jQuery remove <tr> and insert in <tbody>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

I have a `<tr>` which should be removed and added inside a `<tbody>` just before a specific `<tbody>` with `ID`

[image: Image Two]

In this case, `<tr id="general_task_name">` should be added inside `<tbody>` like

`<tbody>
<tr id="general_task_name"></tr>
</tbody>`

just before `<tbody id="task_proj_0">`

`<tr id="general_task_name">` would be fixed and should be added only above `task_proj_0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `tbody` and append the `tr` to it then insert it before the target element

```
$('<tbody />').append($('#general_task_name')).insertBefore('#task_proj_0')
```

Comment: you first solution, the use of before() would result in <tbody></tbody><tr id="general_task_name"></tr> not 
<tbody><tr id="general_task_name"></tr> </tbody>
the new solution sounds plausible to me...

Comment: what about .before() so ?

Comment: I first want it to be removed from exising `<tr>` and then insert  the same before `task_proj_0` inside a `<tbody>`. The above code generates `<tbody>#general_task_name</tbody>`